# Await .then does not wait for the end before returning

Tags: node.js, request

async / await / .then doesn't wait for the function to end before continuing.

```
async function getInfosDatastore(req, res, next) {
    var IP = req.body.IP;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var token = '';
    var cluster = "";
    var policies = "";
    var datastores = "";
    url = 'https://simplivity@' + IP + '/api';
    await getInfos.getToken(url, username, password)
        .then(response => {
            token = response;
            getInfos.getDatastores(token, url)
                .then(response => {
                    datastores = response;
                });
            getInfos.getPolicies(token, url)
                .then(response => {
                    policies = response;
                });
            getInfos.getClusters(token, url)
                .then(response => {
                    cluster = response;
                });
        });
    res.json({ name: datastores, policy: policies, cluster: cluster });
}
```

the output is :
- token
- test
- res.json (but it's empty)
- console.log in each function

it should be : 
- token
- console.log in each function
- test
- res.json with the correct values

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not chaining the inner Promises together with the outer Promise chain. Change to

```
async function getInfosDatastore(req, res, next) {
    const { IP, username, password } = req.body;
    const url = 'https://simplivity@' + IP + '/api';
    const token = await getInfos.getToken(url, username, password);
    const [name, policy, cluster] = await Promise.all([
      getInfos.getDatastores(token, url),
      getInfos.getPolicies(token, url),
      getInfos.getClusters(token, url)
    ]);
    res.json({ name, policy, cluster });
}
```

With the `await Promise.all`, all inner Promises are awaited (and their resolve values extracted) before the interpreter moves on to the next statement.

Also, make sure to put a `catch` onto the caller of `getInfosDatastore` in case one of the Promises rejects, if you haven't already.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this worked. But i don't understand why my react JS doesn't print it. I see it in the data, but not in the ```data.datastores```

Comment: The object you're returning doesn't have a `datastores` property (not in your original function, nor in this one). Did you mean to use the `.name` property?

Comment: ```
               this.setState({
                    namelist: data.datastores,
                    clusterIDlist: data.cluster,
                    policyIDlist: data.policy,
                    submitted: true,
                })
```

I do this in my react to get the values back. I might have inverted both

Comment: Like I said, the object you're returning doesn't have a `datastores` property. Use `.name` instead (or change the function to return an object with a `name` property)

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, because the following 3 callback functions in the function body is executed in the next event loop (in the future)

```
    response => {
        token = response;
        getInfos.getDatastores(token, url)
            .then(response => {
                datastores = response;
            });
        getInfos.getPolicies(token, url)
            .then(response => {
                policies = response;
            });
        getInfos.getClusters(token, url)
            .then(response => {
                cluster = response;
            });
    }
```

What you need to do is to remove the `then` promise method, but make use of `await`