# Call an another API in async await return statement not working

Tags: async-await, axios, vuejs3

I want to call another Axios request after one. But as in the code console. log('skip..) prints first and then my other Axios request runs, But I need to wait for the post-request result and then return the value. If I add await before power bi Axios post request I got an error. Can anyone suggest what to do here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3dra.png)

```
    async getDashboards({commit}, id){
    return await axios.get(`${url}/groups/${group_id}/reports/${id}`)
        .then((resp)=>{
            if(resp.data){
                
                axios.post('https://api', {
                    "datasets": [{'id' : resp.data.datasetId}],
                    "reports": [{'id' : id}], 
                    "targetWorkspaces": [{'id' : resp.data.datasetWorkspaceId }],
                    })
                    .then((dataResp)=>{
                        console.log('dataResp')
                        localStorage.setItem('embedded_token', dataResp.data.token)
                        localStorage.setItem('embedded_token_expiry_time', dataResp.data.expiration)
                        localStorage.setItem('embedded_token_ID', dataResp.data.tokenId)
                    })
                    .catch((error)=>{
                        if(error){
                            return false
                        }
                    })
                console.log('skip...')

                commit('addDashboard', resp.data)
                return resp.data
            }
            return false
        })
        .catch(() => false)
}
```

Comment: There’s no point in doing async/await and also `.then()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Await .then does not wait for the end before returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733996/await-then-does-not-wait-for-the-end-before-returning)

Comment: any suggestion for using await before my Post Axios request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? Await .then does not wait for the end before returning -- No @Terry

Comment: It does. You need to flatten your structure and stop using `.then()` as you are already using async/await.

Comment: If possible can you please re-create the code snippet I wrote above?